# #selector function called unexpectedly

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar

I'm implementing UIToolBar, which has two buttons , "New Directory" and "Edit(or Done)".
I wrote the following code, however, when I pushed "Done button", both of switchMode function and createNewDirectory function is called (latter one should be called from New Directory button only)

Kindly give me any advice.

--
additional comment

I don't use storyboard for toolbar and two buttons. For several reasons, I cannot adopt to use storyboard.

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
@IBAction func goBack(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

var newDirectory: UIBarButtonItem!
var editDirectory: UIBarButtonItem!
var toolbar: UIToolbar!
let flexibleItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
var isEditMode: Bool!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height - 44, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 44))
    newDirectory = UIBarButtonItem(title: "New D", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(createNewDirectory(_:)))
    newDirectory.isEnabled = false
    newDirectory.tintColor = UIColor.init(white: CGFloat(bitPattern: 0), alpha: CGFloat(bitPattern: 0))

    editDirectory = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(switchMode(_:)))
    editDirectory.tintColor = self.view.tintColor

    isEditMode = false

    toolbar.items = [newDirectory, flexibleItem, editDirectory]
    self.view.addSubview(toolbar)
}

func createNewDirectory(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("createNewDirectory was called", sender.title!)
}

func switchMode(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("switchMode was called", sender.title!, isEditMode)
    if isEditMode == false {
        isEditMode = true
        newDirectory.isEnabled = true
        newDirectory.tintColor = self.view.tintColor
        sender.title = "Done"

    } else {
        isEditMode = false
        newDirectory.isEnabled = false
        newDirectory.tintColor = UIColor.init(white: CGFloat(bitPattern: 0), alpha: CGFloat(bitPattern: 0))
        sender.title = "Edit"
    }
}
// some other function not related to this post
```

--

Thanks for many helpful comments!
To simplify, I re-created a sample project and reproduced the issue.

- removed Main Storyboard and related setting
- use Swift 3.3
- swift classes are AppDelegate.swift and ViewController.Swift only. (codes are below)

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let viewController = ViewController()
        self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var newDirectory: UIBarButtonItem!
    var editDirectory: UIBarButtonItem!
    var toolbar: UIToolbar!
    let flexibleItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    var isEditMode: Bool!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height - 44, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 44))
        newDirectory = UIBarButtonItem(title: "New D", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(createNewDirectory(_:)))
        newDirectory.isEnabled = false
        newDirectory.tintColor = UIColor.init(white: CGFloat(bitPattern: 0), alpha: CGFloat(bitPattern: 0))

        editDirectory = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(switchMode(_:)))
        editDirectory.tintColor = self.view.tintColor

        isEditMode = false

        toolbar.items = [newDirectory, flexibleItem, editDirectory]
        self.view.addSubview(toolbar)
    }

    @objc func createNewDirectory(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("createNewDirectory was called", sender.title!)
    }

    @objc func switchMode(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("switchMode was called", sender.title!, isEditMode)
        if isEditMode == false {
            isEditMode = true
            newDirectory.isEnabled = true
            newDirectory.tintColor = self.view.tintColor
            sender.title = "Done"

        } else {
            isEditMode = false
            newDirectory.isEnabled = false
            newDirectory.tintColor = UIColor.init(white: CGFloat(bitPattern: 0), alpha: CGFloat(bitPattern: 0))
            sender.title = "Edit"
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: From the code above I cannot see why this would happen. There must be something else within the project that is causing this.

Comment: Off-topic: Which version of Swift are you using? @objc was mandatory after Swift 4. Earlier versions infer it.

Comment: You have a wonderful debugger. Debug! Put a breakpoint on both methods. When the method is called, you will immediately see why it is being called.

Comment: I use switt3.3 and my deployment target is 10.0. I spent my whole day to this mysterious issue and I used debugger of course! ><

Comment: you need to provide more more code to reproduce this problem. From what you provided it should work

Comment: Are you sure you're outlets are well-connected without any redundancies?

Comment: I rebooted my iOS simulator, and now it worked. I couldn't re-produce the issue now anymore and not quite sure (quite a mystery). anyway. I'll close this. thanks!
( for the last comment, I don't use storyboard, only the codes in the question was what i created in the project)

Comment: everything looks good, haven't loaded into a project. instead of setting the items property have you tried calling the setItem(...)  and passing the array? Also shouldn;t you be using UITabBarItem? UITabBar I thought worked with UITabBarItems as it's array of buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rebooted the iOS simulator and worked fine now.
Not quite sure for the exact reason why it didn't work properly before.
but anyway with this answser I'll close. thanks everyone.

--

For this issue, I created three projects in total.
All of them have the same logic and failed in the same way.
After rebooting the simulator, all of them worked fine.
So this seems to be caused by simulator internal issue or something.